# Can you create a rest api to display info from another site?

Tags: rest

So far all the guides I've found for creating rest API's are for displaying stuff from your own site, but can you display stuff from another site?

Comment: Would you host the API on your server and scrape the other site for info?

Comment: Yes I would host the API on my own server.

Comment: So then sure you *could* do it.  You would need to accept the Request on your server, figure out what you wanted to get and then scrape the other site for the info (but I would question why one needs to do this, and if doing this would be in violation of the other sites policies, etc..)

Comment: I need to create a psn leader board for my clan but there aren't any apis publicly available. I want to use psnprofiles to return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd do this by:

- **Proxying calls:** When a request comes into your server, make a request to the remote server and pass it back to the user. You'll want to make sure you can make the requests quickly and cache results aggressively. You'll probably want to use a short timeout for the remote call and rate-limit API requests so your server can't be blocked making all these remote calls.
- **Pre-fetching:** Downloading with a data dump periodically or pre-fetching the data you need so you can store it locally.

Keep in mind:

- Are you allowed to use the API this way, according to its terms of use? If it's a website you're scraping, it may be okay for small hobby use, but not for a large commercial operation.
- The remote source probably has its own rate limits in place. Can you realistically provide your service under those limits?
- As mentioned, cache aggressively to avoid re-requesting the same data. Get to know HTTP caching standards (cache-control, etag, etc headers) to minimise network activity.
- If you are proxying, consider choosing a data center near the API's data center to reduce latency.